# How to select a binary in app store uploaded before creating the app version in itunes connect?

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

I've updated my app to version 1.2 and uploaded the binary to the store. Than I opened itunes connect and added the new version. Now I am stuck because I have to select a build but my new version 1.2 is not available and without a build I can
t save my changes. I am also not able to upload it again because the binary already exists on the server.

How can I select the binary I've already uploaded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some time and some refreshes of the page, I noticed a small + sign next to the Build headline. Click on this and you can select the build.

I am sure it wasn't there before...